# Floating bar + bar to compare values to a "reference"

Tags: dimple.js

I would like to draw a vertical bar chart with "reference" value that changes for each bar. For instance, let's say I'm drawing the level of sales for this season, and I want to compare it to the level of sales of the previous season.

I know I can draw a two series bar chart, but I prefer this way as it gives a lot more emphasis on the actual season.

I have managed to draw a floating vertical bar over a "regular" vertical bar, but I would like to set the floating bar larger than the "regular" vertical bar. Both series NEED to share the same scale and min-max points.

Oh and ideally, I would like to set the color of the "reference" serie (previous season) to black without taking the place of the other colours (I'm using a color palette to draw series, and each serie has its own color from one chart to another). Would it be possible?

Below is a picture of what I am trying to achieve, plus my code so far:

Picture: https://flic.kr/p/oXKWhU

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>


<div class="chartContainerMax" id="chart1" style="height:600px"></div>


<body>



<script type="text/javascript">

    var chart = dimple.newSvg("#chart1", "100%", "100%");
    d3.csv("data/test.csv", function (data) {
        data = dimple.filterData(data, "Owner", ["Aperture", "LexCorp"]) // Filtering values
        var myChart = new dimple.chart(chart, data);
        myChart.setMargins("10%", "5%", "5%", "10%")
            var xAxis = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month");
            xAxis.addOrderRule("Date");
            var yAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Price");
            var yyAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis(yAxis, "Distribution");
            myChart.addSeries("Season",  dimple.plot.bar, [xAxis, yAxis]);
            var myRef = myChart.addSeries("Previous",  dimple.plot.bar, [xAxis, yyAxis]);
            myRef.stacked = false;
            //myRef.dimpleColor("#292E3A");
            //myRef.shapes.selectAll("rect").attr("transform", "translate(0, -100)");
            //myRef.shapes.selectAll("rect").attr("color", "black");
            myChart.addLegend("5%", "5%", "90%", "10%", "right");
        myChart.draw();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice would be welcome.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the example below should contain examples of all the elements you are looking for (and a couple more):

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400),
    data = [
       { "Category": "a", "Current": 123456789, "Previous":153456789 },
       { "Category": "b", "Current": 234567890, "Previous":204567890 }
    ],
    chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data),
    x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Category"),
    yCurrent = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Current"),
    // Note this references the y axis instead of a string, this creates a composite
    // axis with 2 measures on a single axis
    yPrevious = chart.addMeasureAxis(yCurrent, "Previous"),
    stackedSeries = chart.addSeries("Stacked", dimple.plot.bar, [x, yCurrent]);
    floatingSeries = chart.addSeries("Floating", dimple.plot.bar, [x, yPrevious]);

// Set a narrower stacked bar
stackedSeries.barGap = 0.3;
// Set the second series to floating
floatingSeries.stacked = false;
// Set the bar height
yPrevious.floatingBarWidth = 15;
// Set a title for the y axis
yCurrent.title = "Sales";
// Set a specific colour for the floating bars
chart.assignColor("Floating", "black", "black", 1);

chart.draw();
```

Here it is in action: http://jsbin.com/hosobo/8/edit?js,output

Comment: A million thanks John, this is exactly what I wanted.